# How to log and view the messages caught by try-catch block in Servlets?

Tags: java

Here is my try-catch block:

```
try {
    return dbConnection.createStatement();
} catch(SQLException sqle) {
    // TODO SQL Exception
    System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
}
```

Is it correct to use `System.out` object in Servlets?

What is the easiest way for debugging purposes?

I wanted the message to be printed in the error page generated by the server, eg: `HTTP Status 500`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct to use System.out in the servlet. One option is to simply forward to an error page using your RequestDispatcher:

```
  RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);
```

In addition you can store the exception object in the request scope before forwarding to the error page so that the error is customized.

```
 try {
   return dbConnection.createStatement();
 }   catch(SQLException sqle) {
    // TODO SQL Exception
    request.setAttribute("ex", sqle);
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
  }
```

Then on error.jsp you can take that exception and print out some details.

Answer (score 3):

The user most likely doesn't care, nor understands, what the actual error is. Instead,  show a generic but lively error page, and log the actual error by using something like log4j.

Comment: This is my question. How to use log4j and where is the result shown?

Comment: A quick search for jog4j in servlets will give you everything that you need to set it up. [This page](http://blog.idleworx.com/2010/01/setting-up-log4j-for-simple-java-web.html) for instance is simple to follow.

Comment: As TomJ said: try log4j. 

"where is the result shown?" it depends on what server you are using. If you are using tomcat for example please refer to this tutorial:
http://www.laliluna.de/articles/posts/log4j-tutorial.html